# Смёржить два раздельных запроса

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

есть две таблицы

```
branch_1
 id | parent_id | b1_name
----+-----------+---------
  1 |         1 | aaa
  2 |         1 | bbb
  3 |         1 | ccc
  4 |         2 | ddd
  5 |         2 | eee
  6 |         2 | fff
  7 |         2 | ggg
  8 |         2 | hhh

branch_2
 id | b2_name | parent_id
----+---------+-----------
  1 | b2_aa   |         1
  2 | b2_ba   |         2
  3 | b2_bb   |         2
  4 | b2_bc   |         2
```

И два простых запроса

```
select * from branch_1

select * from branch_2
```

Необходимо смёржить результаты и получить такую таблицу

```
 id | b1_name | b2_name
----+---------+---------
  1 | aaa     | b2_aa
  1 | bbb     | ---
  1 | ccc     | ---
  2 | ddd     | b2_ba
  2 | eee     | b2_bb
  2 | fff     | b2_bc
  2 | ggg     | ---
  2 | hhh     | ---
```

Я пробовал так:

```
select p.id, b1.b1_name, b2.b2_name
from parent p
left outer join lateral (select distinct b1.b1_name from branch_1 b1 where b1.parent_id=p.id order by b1.b1_name) as b1 on true
left outer join lateral (select distinct b2.b2_name from branch_2 b2 where b2.parent_id=p.id order by b2.b2_name) as b2 on true
```

и получаю вот такую таблицу:

```
 id | b1_name | b2_name
----+---------+---------
  1 | aaa     | b2_aa
  1 | bbb     | b2_aa
  1 | ccc     | b2_aa
  2 | ddd     | b2_ba
  2 | ddd     | b2_bb
  2 | ddd     | b2_bc
  2 | eee     | b2_ba
  2 | eee     | b2_bb
  2 | eee     | b2_bc
  2 | fff     | b2_ba
  2 | fff     | b2_bb
  2 | fff     | b2_bc
  2 | ggg     | b2_ba
  2 | ggg     | b2_bb
  2 | ggg     | b2_bc
  2 | hhh     | b2_ba
  2 | hhh     | b2_bb
  2 | hhh     | b2_bc
```

Такой результат мне не подходит, дело в том, что при фасетном поиске через sphinx:

```
select * from facetIndex facet b1_name, b2_name
```

не верно считаются количество товаров. А всё потому, что значения повторяются. По этому стал вопрос, как соединить два запроса так, что значения не повторялись?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table branch_1 (id int,parent_id int, b1_name varchar(32));
create table branch_2 (id int,parent_id int, b2_name varchar(32));

insert into branch_1 values(1,1,'aaa');
insert into branch_1 values(2,1,'bbb');
insert into branch_1 values(3 ,         1 , 'ccc');
insert into branch_1 values(4 ,         2 , 'ddd');
insert into branch_1 values(5 ,         2 , 'eee');
insert into branch_1 values(6 ,         2 , 'fff');
insert into branch_1 values(7 ,         2 , 'ggg');
insert into branch_1 values(8 ,         2 , 'hhh');

insert into branch_2 (id,b2_name,parent_id) values(1 , 'b2_aa'   ,         1);
insert into branch_2 (id,b2_name,parent_id) values(2 , 'b2_ba'   ,         2);
insert into branch_2 (id,b2_name,parent_id) values(3 , 'b2_bb'   ,         2);
insert into branch_2 (id,b2_name,parent_id) values(4 , 'b2_bc'   ,         2);

select
    parent.id, b1_name, b2_name
from (
     select 1 id
    union select 2
 ) parent
inner join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by parent_id) rn from branch_1
) br1 on br1.parent_id = parent.id
left join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by parent_id) rn  from branch_2
) br2 on br2.parent_id = br1.parent_id and br1.rn = br2.rn
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я решил уже эту задачу более похожим вариантом `select t.id, t.b1_name, b2.b2_name
from (
  select p.id, b1.b1_name, row_number() over (partition by p.id order by b1_name) as rn
  from parent p
    join branch_1 b1 on b1.parent_id = p.id
) t
  left join (
    select parent_id, b2_name, 
           row_number() over (partition by parent_id) as rn
    from branch_2 
  ) b2 on b2.parent_id = t.id and b2.rn = t.rn
order by t.id;`

Comment: @bemulima SO одобряет ответы на собственные вопросы, так что в следующий раз не забывай постить ;)